# Help understanding this passage

Tags: meaning

首次在天空中被人目击不到两年之后，中国新型“空警”-500预警机已经加入现役。“空警”-500预警机可以同时对470公里范围内的60多架飞机进行跟踪。“空警”-500“空中预警与控制系统”(AWACS)看起来更像是美国的空中预警机(其上部有圆形雷达穹顶)，但体积小一些，由运-9四引擎涡轮螺旋桨飞机(类似于美国的C-130)搭载。

I know what the first sentence means, but what I am getting from this passage is that the AWACS is slightly smaller than the 空中预警机 and needs transporting by another vehicle, but a search on google images shows that it is an independent jet.  This is from sina.com

Answer (score 2):

Hope I didn't make too many mistakes! Makes a change from my text book!

首次在天空中被人目击不到两年之后，

For the first time in the air in 2 years,

中国新型“空警”-500预警机已经加入现役。

China's new type of 'sky patrol' early warning aircraft has joined active service.

“空警”-500预警机可以同时对470公里范围内的60多架飞机进行 跟踪。

This 'sky patrol'-500 early warning aircraft can simultaneously track more than 60 aircraft within a radius of 470 Kilometers.

“空警”-500“空中预警与控制系统”(AWACS)

'Sky patrol'-500 airborne early warning and control system (AWACS)

看起来更像是美国的空中预警机，

resembles the American airborne early warning system

(其上部有圆形雷达穹顶)

(whose upper section is a circular radar dome)

但体积小一些，

however, the dome is somewhat smaller,

由运-9四引擎涡轮 螺旋桨飞机

The aeroplane is powered by 4 Yun-9 turboprop engines

(类似于美国的C-130)搭载。

(similar to the American C-130) transporter aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

AWACS is abbreviation of Airborne Warning and Control System and it's just a control system that need to be set on a jet. 
空中预警机 is an independent jet that has AWACS on it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a introduction to the "“空警”-500预警机", it's a type of military alert aircraft.

> 首次在天空中被人目击不到两年之后，中国新型“空警”-500预警机已经加入现役。

told us it had been tested for two years before been equipted by PLA and unavoidably been exposed.

> “空警”-500预警机可以同时对470公里范围内的60多架飞机进行跟踪。

It's able to track 60 separate aircrafts within 470 km.

> “空警”-500“空中预警与控制系统”(AWACS)看起来更像是美国的空中预警机(其上部有圆形雷达穹顶)，

The AWACS(The same meaning: [AEW&C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_early_warning_and_control) System) makes it look like one that made in US since there is a rounded shell that contains radar.

> 但体积小一些，由(类似于美国的C-130)搭载。

However, its size is smaller than the US one and its carried by the plain "运-9四引擎涡轮螺旋桨飞机" which looks like C-130.

Answer (score 0):

The AWACS is a system, carried by a jet, since this jet is fully served as a carrier of this warning system, we can refer this jet as a airborne warning and control system too.

I figure what made you confused is that AWACS mean a system and a jet at the same time in paragraph you quoted, just to know that 系统(system) can be a concept, an idea, a theory, or an object.

To be clear, let's take a look at this paragraph again: 
首次在天空中被人目击不到两年之后，中国新型“空警”-500预警机(***`a jet with the warning system`***)已经加入现役。“空警”-500预警机(***`a jet with the warning system`***)可以同时对470公里范围内的60多架飞机进行跟踪。“空警”-500“空中预警与控制系统”(AWACS)(***`a jet with the warning system`***)看起来更像是美国的空中预警机(***`a jet with warning system`***)(其上部有圆形雷达穹顶)，但体积小一些(***`空警-500 jet is smaller than the US jet with the warning system`***)，由运-9四引擎涡轮螺旋桨飞机(类似于美国的C-130)搭载。